# How to hide urls in Django Rest Framework api?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF, and I want to noone know what urls my project has. So when you go to link like localhost:8000/api/ you can see browsable api, I already hide it by following settings:

```
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
),
```

but it still shows me available urls in json format.

How to hide these urls?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You likely want to use [`SimpleRouter`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter) instead of `DefaultRouter`